# Automata with rules and invariances

Tags: alloy

I was inspired by the slide http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/tutorials/day-course/s4_dynamic.pdf of Greg Dennis and Rob Seater, to model an automaton whose transitions are defined by rules and invariances but I can not understand why satisfy the constraints even in the presence of invariances and contradictory rules.

```
sig State {value : one Int}
sig System { trans : State -> State }
pred i1[s : State] { s.value < 4 }
pred i2[s : State] { s.value > 0 }
pred r1[s, s' : State, m, m' : System] { 
  s.value = -1 and s'.value = 0 and change[s, s', m, m']
}
pred r2[s, s' : State, m, m' : System] { 
  s.value = 1 and s'.value = 2 and change[s, s', m, m']
}
pred change[s, s' : State, m, m' : System] { 
  m'.trans = m.trans + s -> s' 
}
assert ruleSafe { 
  all s, s' : State, m,m' : System | 
  i1[s] and i2[s] and r1[s,s',m,m'] and r2[s,s',m,m'] => 
  i1[s'] and i2[s']
}
check ruleSafe
```

Comment: I did not understand your question. What did you expect to happen? What contradictory rules are you talking about and how would they fail to satisfy the constrains?

Answer (score 0):

*First, a side note:  It's not clear what the `value` relation is intended to be doing, but do remember that integers in Alloy tend to be very narrow and overflow behavior can make rules like `s.value < 4` produce unexpected results.  Whenever integers are used only to ensure a nice supply of distinct values, or ordered values it is almost always better to use an uninterpreted type in Alloy with some relations to ensure the necessary constraints.*

However, that's not the main source of your confusion.  I think you believe that since `r1` requires its first argument to have a `value` of -1 and `r2` requires the same argument to have a `value` of 1, any condition involving both `r1` and `r2` with the same first argument cannot possibly be satisfied, and there can be no instances of a model which is required to satisfy such a predicate.  Almost true!

I think you're correct that `r1` and `r2` cannot both be true for the same set of arguments (or any sets of arguments with the same first argument `s`).  But the constraint you specify uses `r1[s,s',m,m'] and r2[s,s',m,m']` in the *antecedent* of a *conditional*.  Before you go any further, stop and think:  What is the truth value of a conditional if the antecedent is false?

If you are having trouble seeing what is going on, try examining the instances of your model in which the antecedent of your conditional is true for all pairs of States and Systems.  Concretely, add the following to your model and look at the instances it produces.

```
pred antecedent {
  all s, s' : State, m, m' : System
  | i1[s] and i2[s] and r1[s,s',m,m'] and r2[s,s',m,m']
}
run antecedent
```

It took me a minute or two before I understood what I was seeing; if it takes you longer than a few minutes, you might try the following variant definition of `antecedent` and see if it enlightens you.

```
pred antecedent {
  all s, s' : State, m, m' : System
  | i1[s] and i2[s] and r1[s,s',m,m'] and r2[s,s',m,m']
  some State
  some System
}
```

You are not the first user of first-order logic to have been taken by surprise when a conditional statement in your model turned out to be vacuously true when you expected it to be false.  You won't be the last.

Comment: "value" in State is the value associated with a state. Missing the fact that no exist two distinct states with the same value. But aside from this clarification, the idea is to model an automaton that would manage only been admissible, or subject to the invariant and only have transitions expressed by predicates. I do not understand where I wrong in this approach.